# Constructing a generic java class where T is a class foo or a subclasses of foo

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a class `Foo` with subclass `SubFoo`, a collection class `FooListing`.

I want to create a generic `FooListing<T>` where `T` is either `Foo` or a subclass of `Foo`

From the wording of the [documentation](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/generics/) (under 'Wildcards'), it sounds like

```
public class FooListing<T extends Foo> { ... }
```

...would let me use `FooListing<SubFoo>`, but not `FooListing<Foo>`, is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're already fine - what you've got allows `T` to be `Foo`.

I've tried to find the relevant bit of the spec, but unfortunately it's extremely opaque :( It definitely works though!

Comment: Agreed, it works in practice! I just couldn't find anyone explicitly stating this one way or another..

Comment: Yes, this will work. The generic T will become a Foo when compiled. So you can use any T which extends Foo (or even Foo itself) because of casting rules.

In case you don't set any supertype for the generic type setting, it will become an Object when compiled. Because, then you want to allow each and every type for your class, so it has to be castable to any type and only Object is able to serve this.